# How to automaticly publish images in silverstripe dataextension

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I was trying to add an uploadfield to a Custom DataExtension and got the Image field working. However the image i uploaded stays in concept mode, and i have to go to the File tab to publish it. I tried to use the code provided in the Silverstripe documentation but this only seems to work on regular pages. I found a question similar to mine:[How to automaticaly publish files uploaded to a dataobject in Silverstripe model admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144600/how-to-automaticaly-publish-files-uploaded-to-a-dataobject-in-silverstripe-model/48149468#48149468)  however this only seems to work on DataObjects.

This is my current code:

```
<?php
use SilverStripe\Forms\LiteralField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;
use SilverStripe\Forms\HTMLEditor\HTMLEditorField;
use SilverStripe\AssetAdmin\Forms\UploadField;
use SilverStripe\Assets\Image;
use SilverStripe\Assets\Storage\AssetStore;
use SilverStripe\Versioned\Versioned;
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension;

class CustomSiteConfig extends DataExtension 
{   
    private static $db = [          
    ];      

    private static $has_one = [
        'Logo' => Image::class
    ];  

    private static $owns = [
        'Logo'
    ];  

    private static $extensions = [
        Versioned::class,
    ];  

    private static $versioned_gridfield_extensions = true;  

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) 
    {
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Header", LiteralField::create("","<h1>Header</h1>"));                  
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Header", UploadField::create('Logo', 'Logo'));                     
    }       
}
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's currently a bug that prevents "owned" records to be published if the owning dataobject is not versioned.

I think you're experience this bug, since `SiteConfig` is not versioned and thus won't publish owned files/images when it's being saved.

Until this bug has been resolved, you could use an `onAfterWrite` hook in your extension to publish the file:

```
public function onAfterWrite()
{
    if ($this->owner->LogoID) {
        $this->owner->Logo()->publishSingle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh i did not know that there was a bug in the SiteConfig but thanks for you help! This piece of code solved the problem i was having.

Comment: It's not a problem in SiteConfig, but rather with all DataObjects that are unversioned and have a relation to a versioned resource.

Comment: Hi @bummzak, I tried this piece of code in my current project, where I'm doing the same exactly thing. On ```dev``` and ```test``` environment works splendidly, but in ```live``` version it throws a ```There has been an error``` exception - with no traces. Seems that the condition not passing - it not intercept ```LogoID```. With ```$this->owner->Logo()``` works, but throws that error. Any suggestion?