# SilverStripe 4 - DataExtension auto-publish versioned files error

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

As stated by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008047/how-to-automaticly-publish-images-in-silverstripe-dataextension), the workaround proposed works very well on `dev` and `test` SS environments. 
The suggested one is to avoid the current bug related to auto-publish files managed via `DataObject` `$owns` property.

But since I uploaded my project in production - on `live` env - the workaround doesn't work anymore.

In my case I'm working on a `DataExtension` of `User` model. The rest of implementation follows exactly the above mentioned case - with `UploadField`.
In production, it seems that the snippet is ignored in its condition. In particular, this is my version:

**UserExtension**

```
// AllegatiDownload: many_many File type uploaded with UploadField
public function onAfterWrite()
{
    if ($this->owner->AllegatiDownloadID) { // <- This is being ignored in live version
        $this->owner->AllegatiDownload()->publishSingle();
    }

    parent::onAfterWrite();
}
```

If I try to replace

`$this->owner->AllegatiDownloadID`

with

`$this->owner->AllegatiDownload()`

The condition pass, but `$this->owner->AllegatiDownload()->publishSingle()` returns an untraced 500 exception. Just:

> There was been an error

And, as I said, this happens only in production.

Thanks in advance for support.

Comment: Can you set up some logging on your live site to track the error caused when you see "There has been an error"? I don't know why model relationships would be any different between dev, test or live

Comment: Sorry but no log being generated after this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I flushed the project DB in order to upgrade a custom front-end component that interacts with it. Seems that after that flush, the issue being solved. That's pretty strange, because I tried many `/dev/build?flush=all` before, and nothing happened. Server cache maybe? I don't know. But now the workaround works as expected.

Thanks anyway for the support.